# How do I set a background image for a component in Angular?

Tags: angular

So I want my component, located in “src/app/login/login.component.html" to have a a background image called ‘office.jpg’ located in a folder called images “src/images/office.jpg”.

So the code in my “login.component.html” file is as follows, which I found earlier after a quick google search:

```js
<div [style.background]="'url(../images/' + office.jpg + ')'">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.FIRSTNAME }}</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

However I do get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'jpg' of undefined

I do not understand where I have gone wrong. How do I add the image as my background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax that you are using is for when image name is a variable
As the image name is constant in this case you can use like this

As it is static you can also set this in css

```
<div [style.background]="'url(../images/office.jpg)'">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.FIRSTNAME }}</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```